# Can't login to Ubuntu Core 16 using a second ssh key

Tags: ssh, login, ubuntu-core

I just installed Ubuntu Core 16 on a Raspberry Pi 2. Before install, I uploaded my ssh key for one of my computers to my Ubuntu SSO account. After installation I had no problems connecting to the Pi using my key and Ubuntu SSO Username. Then I wanted to be able to connect to the Pi from another machine and I generated a new key which I then added to the same account.

The problem is that logging in using this second key does not work.

If I take a look at my authorized_keys file on the Pi, it contains only the first key which explains why login from the second machine doesn't work. How do I get my second key in there? I guess I could do it manually but it seems like the wrong way to do it, given the cloud integration and all.

Comment: Was going to ask this question. Seems to be related to this posted bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1646559. Currently there is no automatic refresh but it's not even clear if it's possible to tell the Ubuntu Core to sync with the SSO account to get a 2nd key.

Comment: Thanks a lot Josh, that explains it. I had really expected this feature to be ready by now. However, I encounter other issues with Ubuntu Core so I ended up going with Ubuntu Mate instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SSH keys are imported once during `console-conf` into your user's home directory `~/.ssh/`. Therefore, if you mount the `writable` partition on a different Linux machine you can manually append the missing SSH public key(s) to `/writable/user-data/username/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

This worked on a WDLabs Nextcloud Box running Ubuntu Core 16 and Nextcloud 11.