# Ubuntu Core - How to get new public keys installed

Tags: ssh, security, ubuntu-core, keyrings

This may be a trivial question for some as I am new to working with Ubuntu Core.  Is there a way to get a new public key installed if you don't have a previous method for authenticating?

I had a raspberry pi running from a previous install which had two public keys from my SSO account installed. The problem is that I needed to access the device from a new machine which uses a public key that is not in the `authorized_keys` directory and I could no longer use a previous machine that was authorized to update this file.

Is there a way to do this , given that by nature username/password authentication is disabled ?  The only way I could find to recover is to re-image the device and go through console setup again where it re-imports the public keys (including my new one) from my SSO account.  I feel I'm missing something.  Thanks.

Comment: You're not missing anything, this sounds like [bug #1646559](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1646559).

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions all referenced in one location (here):

[How do I add SSH Keys to authorized_keys file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46424/how-do-i-add-ssh-keys-to-authorized-keys-file)

[Can't login to Ubuntu Core 16 using a second ssh key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865334/cant-login-to-ubuntu-core-16-using-a-second-ssh-key)

[[SOLVED] Cannot ssh into Ubuntu Core 16](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2373399)