# How to force synchronization of SSH autherized keys from Ubuntu One account to Ubuntu Core IoT device

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-one, ubuntu-core, keys

I added a few more SSH keys to the Ubuntu One account (https://login.ubuntu.com/ssh-key).

Now, I want to make sure that these key are now sent down to the IoT devices that have Ubuntu Core installed on it.  I can see the keys on the Ubuntu Core IoT devices by running the following command:

```
cat ./.ssh/authorized_keys
```

How or what is the procedure of getting the new keys send down to the IoT devices?

Comment: Read `man -k inotify`. You can monitor a file/directory, and trigger a script/command when it changes. And read `man ssh-copy-id`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't login to Ubuntu Core 16 using a second ssh key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865334/cant-login-to-ubuntu-core-16-using-a-second-ssh-key). Note that there is no mechanism to *reload* ssh keys from Ubuntu One.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't login to Ubuntu Core 16 using a second ssh key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865334/cant-login-to-ubuntu-core-16-using-a-second-ssh-key)

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism to *reload* ssh keys from Ubuntu One. (Unless you reset/wipe-and-reinstall the system)

After you have access to your Ubuntu Core system, you place additional keys directly instead of via Ubuntu One. Append the new key to the `/writable/user-data/username/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

- **NOTE** that directory is different from every other flavor of Ubuntu. It applies to Ubuntu Core only.

Ubuntu One is merely a link in the chain of trust for the user's first login.

- After a successful first login, the core system does NOT check with Ubuntu One again. It doesn't need to: It has a working key now.
- There are alternatives to the Ubuntu One key download: [Cloud-Init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/examples.html) and [System User Assertions](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/reference/assertions/system-user). These methods, like the Ubuntu Core method, create new users and their associated keys. These methods also cannot be used to reset/update/reload keys of existing users.